# return to libc attack using a function pointer

Tags: security, buffer-overflow, libc, exploit, shellcode

How should I format my input for the return to libc attack in the following code:

```
void example_function(int x, const char *name)
{
    void (*foo)(int, const char *) = http_serve_none;
    char buf[1024];

    sprintf(buf, name);

    foo(x, buf);
}
```

Given that the stack is non executable. I want to do return to libc attack by changing foo function pointer to system in libc and not by changing the return address of example_function. What I've done so far is used the conventional method for the input:

> padding + address of system ( at foo function's address ) + address of
>   exit + ptr to string ( string = "/bin/sh" )

but however this is not working. I don't know how to format my argument in input string for system call. I searched a lot on internet but everywhere I saw  calling system() using return address only.

Extra Assumption:

there are no '0' in system call address. Machine is 32 bit and sprintf is working properly i.e, storing name into the buffer buf[1024].

Comment: hw for a class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it finally... I just passed pointer to string "/bin/sh" at address of x and it worked for me

Answer (score 0):

First, make sure your `sprintf` is actually `sprintf` and not `__sprintf_chk` which is going to try to thwart your overflow. You can tell it's the fortify version because you'll get a SIGABRT rather than something else (like SIGSEGV). You can turn off fortify globally, but you can also just get avoid the macro like:

```
(sprintf)(buf, name);
```

Your next problem is zeros. If the address of `system` has any zero bytes in it, then the `sprintf` is going to stop copying at that point. This is both "well, there are an awful lot of 64-bit addresses with zeros in them," and intentional. It's called ASCII armoring, and on some platforms important libc functions are made sure to have zeros in them to stop exactly this attack. (See [Writing a return-to-libc attack, but libc is loaded at 0x00 in memory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7779534/writing-a-return-to-libc-attack-but-libc-is-loaded-at-0x00-in-memory) for a little more on that.)

You may want to explore this attack using a function in your program (i.e. not libc) that you've ensured has no zeros in it. That's a bit easier to do if you build for 32-bit. And of course, you probably want to turn off fortify and stack protection and all the other things that the compiler is doing to stop this :D (at least until you have have a basic version working; then you can turn those on one at a time).

Comment: I've clarified these things in the question now.  please tell me how to call system()  in libc to execute shellcode using foo()

Comment: The code should be very short so you should be able to post it. It's also critical to say what you mean by "doesn't work." Does it crash? Where and how? Run the debugger on it. What is the value of name and foo right before it's executed?

Comment: Is there a zero anywhere in your payload? Remember, it's going to stop copying at that point.

Comment: (and you have turned off ASLR, right? Otherwise `system()` isn't where you think it is.)

Comment: ASLR is turned off and there is no 0 in my payload

Comment: @davidwatson well you could post it on Github and paste the link. I do that regularly here.

Comment: A basic attack should be pretty small. Have you reduced this down to the smallest test version? Start with a `buf` size of zero, so you don't have to worry about padding. And get rid of any parsing from the commandline; just hard-code everything until you get it working.